# Archive for required library: '/System/Library/Java/Extensions/dns_sd.jar' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: eclipse

I'm using a mac.  I downloaded Eclipse first, then jdk after the first time around.  I have since reinstalled eclipse and jdk multiple times, turned my computer off and on again multiple times, and gotten the same error every time.  In my project, I can see the dns_sd.jar file in the JRE System Library, but apparently eclipse doesn't recognize it.  I tried making a folder and putting a copy of the file in it, then adding that to the build path, but that didn't fix it; it actually made more of the same error on the file.  Is it just that the dns_sd.jar is corrupted?  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Yes, it seems quite clear the file does not contain what you think it should. What do you see if you try `file /System/Library/Java/Extensions/dns_sd.jar` ? And if you copy somewhere else, rename it to dns_sd.zip, and try to open if with the Finder?

Comment: I copied it to my desktop, renamed it to .zip, and when I opened it, it made  dns_sd.zip.cgpz.  When I opened that, it made dns_sd 2.zip

Comment: Hmmm it seems to confirm it was corrupted. You need to redownload. See [this page about the issue](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/13/open-zip-cpgz-file/)

Comment: I've since restored my computer (wiped everything) and tried again, only to get the same error.  On a different computer, installing it with exactly the same process worked on the first try.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Did you download that file and put it there, or was it already there in the system? What version of the OS are you using? Can you share details about why that library is needed? And finally please share more details about the error (is it a compile error, runtime error... ?). This is a very peculiar issue, please provide as much info as you can, ideally enough details to allow someone else to try.

Comment: I've since given up on eclipse and am using another IDE, but to clarify: Mac OSX 10.11.6, don't know why it needs that library, the error occurs when I make a new project (or open a previous one), and the file is already there I'm pretty sure (and can't be removed, it said something like it's part of the OS).